# ArrayOutOfBoundIndex on xls Rules

Tags: drools, xls

[ArrayOutOfBound Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2uhm.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJ3wy.png)

I have an xls rule [1 & 2], when I run it as JUnit, it works fine, but when I run it as Maven test, an ArrayOutOfBounds [3] error appears and I couldn't find any explanation. Any hint ?

========================================================

The pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost</groupId>
    <artifactId>bluecost</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>bluecost</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>dev</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>test</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>test</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
            <build>
              <plugins>
                <plugin>
                  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <phase>install</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                      </goals>
                      <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                      </configuration>
                    </execution>
                  </executions>
                </plugin>
              </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <build.profile.id>prod</build.profile.id>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.batch.version>3.0.8.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <mysql.driver.version>5.1.44</mysql.driver.version>
        <db2.driver.version>10.1.0</db2.driver.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Batch dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-infrastructure</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.batch.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- MySQL database driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc_license_cisuz</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2.jcc</groupId>
            <artifactId>db2jcc</artifactId>
            <version>${db2.driver.version}</version>
        </dependency> 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-spring</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.jdt.core</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>bluecost-batch</finalName>
        <filters>
            <filter>profiles/${build.profile.id}/config.properties</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude></exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>           
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <organization>
        <name>IBM Corporation</name>
    </organization>`enter code here`
</project>
========================
```

=====================

And the JUnit I created...

```
@Before
        public void setUp() {
            final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("setup()");
            logger.info("-----------------------------");
        }


        @Test
        public void testDefaultValuesbyChannelName(){

            BlueReport testBlueReport = new BlueReport();
            // Arbitrary value, this should be "SOFTLYER"
            testBlueReport.setAccount_id("29302"); // Must exist
            testBlueReport.setOrg_co("SOFTLYER");


            SSCData testSSCdataOutput = new SSCData();
            testSSCdataOutput.setORIG_LOC_CD(null);   // values will be filled by the rule
            testSSCdataOutput.setSERVICE_CD(null);    // this too will be filled by the rule        



            // values will be filled by the rules
            String expectedOrigLocCd = "SLR";
            //SSCDataOutput.setORIG_LOC_CD("SLR");
            String expectedServiceTypCd = "SLR";
            //SSCDataOutput.setSERVICE_TYP_CD("SLR");
            String expectedServiceCd = "SLIC";
            //SSCDataOutput.setSERVICE_CD("SLIC");
            String expectedServiceGroupId = "BASE";
            //SSCDataOutput.setSERVICE_GROUP_ID("BASE");
            String expectedRateClasCd = "OGS";
            //SSCDataOutput.setRATECLAS_CD("OGS");
            String expectedLocalField1 = "INVCE ID";
            //SSCDataOutput.setLOCAL_FIELD_1("INVCE ID");
            //SSCDataOutput.setLOCAL_FIELD_2(null);//Not anymore at the Invoice level. can be Nulled.
            String expectedLocalField3 = "ACCT ID";
            //SSCDataOutput.setLOCAL_FIELD_3("ACCT ID");
            //SSCDataOutput.setLOCAL_FIELD_5(null);
            //SSCDataOutput.setLOCAL_FIELD_6(null);
            final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("testDefaultValuesbyChannelName");

            dtSession.execute( Arrays.asList(new Object[] { testSSCdataOutput, testBlueReport }) );

            logger.info("Rules that activated: " + testSSCdataOutput.getRuleAudit());


            dtSession.setGlobal("logger", logger);

            logger.info("Expecting ORIG_LOC_CD to be SLR");         
            assertTrue("I expected SLR", testSSCdataOutput.getORIG_LOC_CD().contains(expectedOrigLocCd));

            logger.info("Expecting SERVICE_CD to be SLIC"); 
            assertTrue("I expected SLIC", testSSCdataOutput.getSERVICE_CD().contains(expectedServiceCd));

            logger.info("Expecting SERVICE_TYPE_CD to be SLR"); 
            assertTrue("I expected SLR", testSSCdataOutput.getSERVICE_TYP_CD().contains(expectedServiceTypCd));

            logger.info("Expecting SERVICE_GROUP_ID to be BASE");   
            assertTrue("I expected BASE", testSSCdataOutput.getSERVICE_GROUP_ID().contains(expectedServiceGroupId));

            logger.info("Expecting RATECLAS_CD to be OGS"); 
            assertTrue("I expected OGS", testSSCdataOutput.getRATECLAS_CD().contains(expectedRateClasCd));

            logger.info("Expecting LOCAL_FIELD1 to be INVCE ID");   
            assertTrue("I expected INVCE ID", testSSCdataOutput.getLOCAL_FIELD_1().contains(expectedLocalField1));

            logger.info("Expecting LOCAL_FIELD3 to be ACCT ID");    
            assertTrue("I expected ACCCT ID", testSSCdataOutput.getLOCAL_FIELD_3().contains(expectedLocalField3));
```

And this is the error on Run As ... 'Maven test'

======================================================

```
Running com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.DroolsDefaultValuesByChannelNameTest
[ERROR] TestContextManager - Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@1de6f05] to prepare test instance [com.ibm.cio.cloud.cost.unit.DroolsDefaultValuesByChannelNameTest@114e780] <java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext>java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:369)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:275)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:239)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:373)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:334)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:119)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:407)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dtBase': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 38851
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:742)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 38851
    at jxl.read.biff.Record.<init>(Record.java:79)
    at jxl.read.biff.File.next(File.java:181)
    at jxl.read.biff.WorkbookParser.parse(WorkbookParser.java:569)
    at jxl.Workbook.getWorkbook(Workbook.java:271)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.parser.xls.ExcelParser.parseFile(ExcelParser.java:77)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:89)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.SpreadsheetCompiler.compile(SpreadsheetCompiler.java:68)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.compileStream(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:37)
    at org.drools.decisiontable.DecisionTableProviderImpl.loadFromInputStream(DecisionTableProviderImpl.java:20)
    at org.drools.compiler.DecisionTableFactory.loadFromInputStream(DecisionTableFactory.java:15)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.decisionTableToPackageDescr(PackageBuilder.java:454)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addPackageFromDecisionTable(PackageBuilder.java:448)
    at org.drools.compiler.PackageBuilder.addKnowledgeResource(PackageBuilder.java:690)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:45)
    at org.drools.builder.impl.KnowledgeBuilderImpl.add(KnowledgeBuilderImpl.java:34)
    at org.drools.container.spring.beans.KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.afterPropertiesSet(KnowledgeBaseBeanFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 42 more
```

Comment: Do you have the same jxl library in the Maven build environment?

Comment: Please provide code, as well as outputting your errors as text rather than images.

Comment: I use the pom.xml to run Maven Test

Comment: The code for pom.xml, error output is quite too long to be posted here, I'm not sure if this stackoverflow can accept file

Comment: Added codes, edited my question

Comment: And yes, I have the same jxl library